# How to correctly restore from a backup.tar.gz file

Tags: boot, 18.04, mount, lubuntu, backup

I have followed this reddit thread on how to backup and restore an ubuntu filesystem. When I try to boot the USB after restoring the backup with the following command:

`sudo tar -xpzf /media/d/backup.tar.gz -C / --numeric-owner` (where d is my pendrive)

I boot with the following errors:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: decoding failed
Found HC with no IRQ. Check BIOS/PCI 0000:
init 0000:00:1a.0 fail, -19
overlayfs: filesystem on /var/lib/docker/overlay2... not supported as upperdir
```

When I access the terminal with ctrl alt f4 I can access the backed-up user and the files. But I can't apt-get as there is no wireless service when I check `ifconfig -a`, only `lo` and `enp2s0`.

Another point of interest is the `/dev/loop0` filesystem is 100% used and mounted on `/rofs` (which I have never seen before).

I also get error messages when logging into the backed-up user, with multiple `permission denied` in `/etc/update-motd.d/...` and `/usr/lib/update-notifier/...` and mount `/lib/x86_64... MOUNT_2.33 not found (required by mount)

I'm at a loss as to how to correctly boot or restore the backup. The ubuntu loading screen appears with the disk being checked but that is the only GUI seen.

Does anyone have any suggestions to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For those having trouble with backups, the `--keep-newer-files` fixed the problem for me.

Check all [flags out here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/tar.htm). And here is Ubuntu's [backup/restore tutorial.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR)